# Evaluate by first adding all other rows to the first row.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$det \left[\begin{matrix} x-1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & -3 & x-2 \\ -2 & x & -2 \end{matrix}\right]$$

I'm not sure I understand the question. I've done $R_1+R_2$ & $R_1+R_3$ which gives me:
$$det \left[\begin{matrix} x-1 & x-1 & x-1 \\ 2 & -3 & x-2 \\ -2 & x & -2 \end{matrix}\right]$$

$$(x-1)det \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -3 & x-2 \\ -2 & x & -2 \end{matrix}\right]$$   $R_2-2R_1$ & $R_3+2R_1$

$$(x-1)det \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -5 & x-4 \\ 0 & x+2 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$

$det=(x-1)(-5(0)-(x-4)(x+2))$=$-(x-1)(x-4)(x+2)$
but then what am I supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the first row will contain only (x-1)'s, and you can expand it with respect to the first row.

Comment: @Botond Even better, after the two row operations, you can write $\ldots = \begin{vmatrix} x-1 & x-1 & x-1 \\ * & *  & * \\  * & * & * \end{vmatrix}
=(x-1)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ * & *  & * \\  * & * & * \end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Yeah I've added what I got. What do you mean? Sorry I feel really dumb because I'm sure it's extremely simple.

Comment: You could add -2 times R1 to R2 and +2 times R1 to R3.

Comment: So should I turn this into RREF or lower triangular form? @Malcolm

Comment: I would go for upper triangular form, but it's a matter of taste.  Do you know cofactor expansion?

Comment: @Malcolm Yes I do, do you recommend I do that instead? I'm thinking I should do what you suggested and then turn into a block matrix and... give me one second I will do it in my question lol.

Comment: Actually I suggest you do both
$(x-1)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -3 & x-2 \\ -2 & x & -2 \end{vmatrix}
=(x-1)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -5 & x-4 \\ 0 & x+2 & 0 \end{vmatrix}
=(x-1)(1)\begin{vmatrix}-5 & x-4 \\ x+2 & 0 \end{vmatrix}$

Comment: @malcom So i did it right in the end? is that the answer?

Comment: Yes!, with two small typos in your final answer.  It should be $(x-4)$ not $(x+4)$ and it should be times (-1).

Comment: @Malcolm where does the (-1) come from?

Comment: $−5(0)−(x−4)(x+2) = 0-(x-4)(x+2) =  -(x-4)(x+2)$

Comment: Ah, okay! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an error in the last line.  It should be $-(x-1)(x-4)(x+2)$.  Depending on taste, you might be asked to expand the products to get a cubic polynomial like $-x^3+3x^2+\ldots$